# How to add a description to django choices?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm just facing the problem that I need to describe the available choices I'm adding to the model.

```
class Limitation(models.Model):
    METHOD_CHOICES = (
        ('sl', 'Soft Limit'),
        ('hl', 'Hard Limit'),
    )
    #...
```

I'd like to display something like...a help-text...if you're selecting an option. So if the user is selecting *"Soft Limit"* I'd like to show *"Allows save operation, will notify admins, will deny any further operation...bla bla bla"*.

Is there anything already built in django available? Or maybe a lightweight workaround?

Comment: You could use a foreignkey relation instead of choices to have more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the selects generated by django are just selects. Where would this help text be displayed with select? Html5 allows title attribute for all elements (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp). But for this element to be displayed you would have to create your own django widget for that. A widget, which accepts not only choices, but choices and help texts. And then renders them as option titles.

That is as lightweight as possible, i guess. Use some js library to make those helptexts pretty too and you are set :)